# Symfony Translations: Soft hyphens (&shy;) in messages yaml file?

Tags: html, symfony, yaml, translation, soft-hyphen

I'm wondering how I can have soft hyphens (­) in a messages yaml file in Symfony?

I'd like to have something like this:

`headline-first: Banana&shy;republic`

Thanks!

Comment: Well, YAML doesn't do HTML, so you'd use the [Unicode soft-hyphen character](https://unicode-explorer.com/c/00AD) instead…?!

Comment: Yes, it works when I do this: headline-first: "Banana\u00ADrepublic"